# Typo3 9.5 Fluid template navigation menu only starts at one page id

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

Working on Typo3 project, we are using Typo3 9.5

There is already an extension created for the project by my colleague, which has a navigation menu going something like this

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

        <v:menu pageUid="2">

            <ul class="navbar-nav">...
```

As you can see v:menu is assigned a hard-coded pageUid.

Is there a way to remove hardcoding so that the extension could be transfered between systems and assigned to various pages without worying about changing the value every time it's done.

I can also see it becoming an issue once we need to run more then one root level layout from this template :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the [documentation of that VH](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/MenuViewHelper.html)

Similar to a [typoscript menu](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html) you can start a menu with an `entryLevel`.

0 = root
1 = first level
2 = second level
:

-1 = current level
-2 = parent level from current
 :

---

if you do not provide the parameter `pageUid` an `entryLevel = 0` is default.

Comment: Typoscript Menu would be my choice, but I am kinda behind on Typo3 so having to go forward with my colleagues decisions as it is essentially his project.

I have to admit that any one of us would of written the site in question in a couple of days using simple technologies like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP and MySQL :-)